# JQuery reference variable not working

Tags: jquery, reference

I am using variable to refer an html div element but it doesnt working.
Can anyone tell me how to fix?

**html tags:**

```
<body>
<button id="btn1" type="button">ClickMe</button><br />
<div id="div1" style="background-color:red;"></div>
</body>
```

**jquery code:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var dv1 = $("#div1");

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    dv1.fadeToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are expecting to have happen. Without that, I'm only guessing.

Comment: Felix has answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your variable `dv1` inside DOM ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dv1 = $("#div1");
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        dv1.fadeToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah it working! Can i make dv1 to global reference variable?